# pythonic dictionary counter?

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

Easiest explained by example:

```
events = ['foo', 'bar', 'biz', 'foo', 'foo']
events_counter = {}
for event in events:
    if event not in events_counter: # {
        events_counter[event] = 1   # {
    else:                           # {
        events_counter[event] += 1  # {
print events_counter

# {'biz': 1, 'foo': 3, 'bar': 1}
```

Is there a way to implement the highlighted code in a more pythonic way? I feel like there should be a built-in function, i.e:

```
events_counter.count_up(event)
```

And yes, I do know I could just write my own procedure, thanks.

Comment: `collections.Counter` is your friend. The question is too easy

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The question is well formatted and clear, just because OP isn't aware of that doesn't make it a bad question necessarily. That said yeah the OP really should of found it googling.

Comment: It didn't occur to you to search for "python counter"?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, where did I say that it's bad? It's duplicate

Comment: `{e: events.count(e) for e in set(events)}`

Comment: The `collections` module is fantastic and built-in to Python. One of the things it contains is a great `Counter` class, which is very flexible. You can read about the module here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python has a built in `Counter` data structure for this:

```
from collections import Counter
events = ['foo', 'bar', 'biz', 'foo', 'foo']
cc = Counter(events)
print(cc)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'foo': 3, 'bar': 1, 'biz': 1})
```

Comment: ahaha apologies, I did briefly look at collections but must've missed it.